# Testing Linux Kernel for an embedded device with diferent Debug options

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto

How can one test a Linux Kernel for a specific Target? Also keeping in mind Point 12 from https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/submit-checklist.html

> 12. Has been tested with CONFIG_PREEMPT, CONFIG_DEBUG_PREEMPT, CONFIG_DEBUG_SLAB, CONFIG_DEBUG_PAGEALLOC, CONFIG_DEBUG_MUTEXES, CONFIG_DEBUG_SPINLOCK, CONFIG_DEBUG_ATOMIC_SLEEP, CONFIG_PROVE_RCU and CONFIG_DEBUG_OBJECTS_RCU_HEAD all simultaneously enabled.

Consider the scenario, I want to compile a Linux Kernel for an ARM based target. I have Linux source files and I code on my Ubuntu Host PC. I did some research and found out that there are Linux Kernel self-tests in tools/testing directory. It says on this [page from kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.16/dev-tools/kselftest.html)
that

> These are intended to be small tests to exercise individual code paths in the kernel. Tests are intended to be run after building, installing and booting a kernel.

But when I run this makefile and execute the script, it tests the kernel on my Host system. And it does not test the source files of the Kernel i want to build.
Is my understanding correct?

What I want to do is run this self-test suite after my ARM Target has been booted. Is this possible ? How can one run these selftests or some other kind of tests for Linux Kernel?

**My knowledge background**: Embedded C developer, Certified Linux Foundation Sysadmin. I have generated custom images for RaspberryPi using Yocto. So i have limited knowledge in Yocto. I have no knowledge in Linux Kernel Driver Development.

Comment: "Tests are intended to be run after building, installing and booting a kernel." - In other words, these tests are intended to be run on the **target machine** which has already booted the kernel and has entered into user mode. After that, you may run the tests using any way described in the docs. If the OS on your embedded device doesn't allow to run executables or doesn't provide C standard library, then you cannot run these tests.

Comment: I did not read that these tests are stored as binaries somewhere in a location like /use/bin or somewhere else in the filesystem / of the booted kernel. I'm still confused.

Comment: They are **compiled** as binaries. You may either compiler them on the target machine, if it has a compiler. Or you may cross-compile them on host and put(copy) resulted binaries into the target.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ok I believe I understand, so do `make` for the particular test, not the native host GCC `make` but from ARM-GCC one and push/copy it to target, execute the test.